# Checking old drives for integrity-health-usage

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have a bunch of old drives that I need to :

1. check for health & integrity
2. Safely erase any possible malware

I'll be using a docking station for this and am very concerned about the correct methodology here.
Will a simple virus scan do or perhaps a sandbox/VM process is better?

Comment: I would boot into a Live Linux environment, format each drive, then run the S.M.A.R.T tools of your choice on each drive.

Comment: What you mean by this question ?